# Cambiar tamaño de íconos Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, icons, bootstrap-5

Necesito modificar el tamaño de los íconos de `bootstrap`. Ya probé con incorporar la clase `fa-x5`, `fa-lg` y no funciona. De paso comento que no estoy usando clases con `fa fa-icon`, sino que son `bi bi-icon`, desconozco también esa diferencia.

El tamaño del `div` es más que suficiente y la etiqueta `style` está funcionando correctamente.

Comment: que version es de bootstrap?

Comment: No lo sé, te dejo los links de mi html:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: Si te funciona, te invito a votar y a marcar como aceptada mi respuesta con el check que aparece al lado izquierdo, de esta forma ambos ganamos reputación en el sitio. De hecho, te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas las reglas de la comunidad.

Comment: Hola @IgnacioGrilli , cualquier ejemplo que pongas deberia ir en la zona de la pregunta para que sea mas accesible y los usuarios lo encuentren mas rapido.
Piensa que mientras mas informacion tengan ellos mas facil sera que te puedan ayudar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Justamente, no te funcionan las clases `fa-x5` porque no estás usando los íconos de `fontAwesome` sino los propios de `Bootstrap` conocidos como `Bootstrap Icons` en la versión 5.

Según la [documentación oficial](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/#styling):

> **Uso:** Bootstrap Icons son SVGs, puedes incluirlos en tu HTML en pocos pasos dependiendo de la configuración de tu proyecto. Recomendamos usar un width: 1em (y opcionalmente height: 1em) para cambiar el tamaño a través de la propiedad CSS font-size.

Por ejemplo:

```css
.bi {
  font-size: 10em;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Stack Overflow</h1>
  <i class="bi bi-stack-overflow"></i>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

O con estilos en línea:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Stack Overflow</h1>
  <i class="bi bi-stack-overflow" style="font-size: 2em;"></i>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta! ahora funciona! muchas gracias!!

Comment: @IgnacioGrilli:  Si funciona por favor márcala como aceptada.